# Create shortcut for static methods / classes

Tags: c#

I have few classes named Verify with static methods inside.

```
namespace Very.Long.Namespace.One{
public class Verify
{
   ///static methods
}
}

namespace Very.Long.Namespace.Two{
    public class Verify
    {
       ///static methods
    }
    }
```

They have very long namespaces and i want to use all of them in other classes avoiding writing:

```
Very.Long.Namespace.One.Verify.Method();
Very.Long.Namespace.Two.Verify.Method();
```

I would like to use them as:

```
One.Method();
Two.Method();
```

But `using One = namespace Very.Long.Namespace.One;` is not the point, because i have a lot of classes where i will use this.

Is there any way to create shortcuts? Classes Verify may be static as well if needed.

Comment: My recommendation is to rename the classes then (if you can).  And after all you'll still need a `using` directive for both to be able to use them in a given class.

Comment: with intellisense it's only a couple of keystrokes anyway. Better to have meaningful clear names, than to worry about saving a second or two of typing. And with a `using` you only have to type it once per file, not a big hardship. There's even this magical thing called copy and paste, or you could write a little script to insert it into multiple files if you have a huge number.

Comment: Just bite the bullet and put the `using` line in each of the source code files where you want a shorter name. It may be a bit of a pain, but it's only one line in each file.

Comment: [using static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) ? Though the scope is the same as alias.

Comment: @Sinatr That would allow them to call the methods directly, but if the methods in each class also have identical names then that wouldn't work when they need both.

Comment: @juharr, you are right, though not only name, signature should match. If parameters are different name can be the same. I just wanted to mention this reducing code length option.

Comment: I have more then those two namespaces and over thousand test classes where i will use them in different combinations. So using this without shortcut is painful.

Comment: maybe a quick powershell script to bulk insert the using statements into the files is the answer then.

Comment: Any specific reason why you have two `Verify` classes? Other than reducing the namespace name, not much else.

Comment: Every verify class is designed for some part of driver. Like verify for car And verify for dog. I'm on design part of system, if You have any suggestions i would be thankful.